# How to lookup the values of a column in a table, if one of its column matches with the other table

Tags: lookup, powerbi, dax

I'm using Power BI desktop. I have 2 tables named as **Company details** and **Tax**. These tables contains a common column **Company ID**. Actually these 2 tables contain different columns but I have only shown the columns needed for this question.

Company details:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| Company UID | Company name |  
+-------------+--------------+
| C1000       | A            |  
| C1400       | B            |  
| C1200       | C            |  
| C1100       | D            |  
| C1300       | E            |  
+-------------+--------------+
```

Tax:

```
+-------------+-----+
| Company UID | FID |  
+-------------+-----+
|       C1000 | F22 |  
|       C1100 | F20 |  
|       C1200 | F22 |  
|       C1300 | F21 |  
|       C1400 | F20 |  
+-------------+-----+
```

Now I need to create a calculated column **Fcode**  in **Company details** which has the values returned by the Existing column **FID** in **TAX** if the values of the column **Company UID** in both the table matches.

Expected result

Company details:

```
+-------------+--------------+-----+
| Company UID | Company name | FID |  
+-------------+--------------+-----+
|       C1000 | A            | F22 |  
|       C1400 | B            | F20 |  
|       C1200 | C            | F22 |  
|       C1100 | C            | F20 |  
|       C1300 | D            | F21 |  
+-------------+--------------+-----+
```

My Dax:

```
    Fcode = IF(VALUES('Company details'[Company UID])=VALUES('Tax'[Company UID]),LOOKUPVALUE('Tax'[FID]), 0))
```

I'm stuck up with what dax should I give in the place of **TrueResult** inside the **If** Loop. so I just tried on giving lookup function. Ofcourse it shows an error. Can anyone suggest what I should replace on behalf of lookup or any other way to get the expected result.

Comment: You DO realise that none of the Company UIDs match, right? The first table has text and the codes start with a letter. The second table has numbers. So, different data types and totally different values.

Comment: @teylyn Apologies. That was the mistake that I made in typing the question. Actually the Company details column in both the tables is of the same data type. the values should be as follows: C1000, C1100, C1200, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can go to "Edit Queries" window. Merge the two tables using inner join and CompanyUID and then strip the results to leave only FID from the second table.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVWSxX-uF-0

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why don't you add relationship between those columns and use RELATED function to get the related FID value from Tax. If you don't want to add relationship then you can still use CROSSJOIN.
Take a look at this article
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-joining-tables/

Comment: If I do CROSSJOIN, the CompanyUIDs of both tables doesn't match.